# Easyadmin 3: Save images in dynamic folders?

Tags: php, symfony, easyadmin

I would like to use an `ImageField` but have the file stored in a dynamic directory (corresponding to the `id` of the entity being created/edited).

I've tried setting the `setUploadDir` and `setBasePath` methods but even though I've managed to set the file name to say `1/foo.jpg` thanks to a setter on my entity, the end file does not get stored in the proper subdirectory. Is it even possible?